# Check constraint with multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table DEPENDENT

```
CREATE TABLE DEPENDANT (DEPENDANT_NM VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  DEP_GENDER CHAR(1), DEP_BDAT DATE, RELATED_HOW VARCHAR2 (8), ESSNO CHAR(9));
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESSNO FOREIGN KEY (ESSNO)
 REFERENCES HW_EMPLOYEE(SSNO);
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DEP_GENDER CHECK
(DEP_GENDER IN ('M','F'));
```

I need to add a constraint that makes sure that female dependents can only be realted as 'daughter' or 'spouse' and male dependents or only 'son' or 'spouse'

Do I use a check constraint like ...

```
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RELATEDF CHECK (DEP_GENDER = 'F' AND 
RELATED_HOW IN('Daughter' OR 'Spouse'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RELATEDF 
        CHECK (DEP_GENDER = 'F' AND RELATED_HOW IN ('Daughter', 'Spouse'));
```

**Edit**: you have to do it in one check:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RELATEDF
  CHECK ((DEP_GENDER = 'F' AND RELATED_HOW IN ('Daughter', 'Spouse'))
    OR (DEP_GENDER = 'M' AND RELATED_HOW IN ('Son', 'Spouse')));
```

Comment: Ok, then I just make an almost identical constraint for males, correct?

Comment: @user1873736 You have to do it in one check, I've edited my answer.

Comment: "you have to do it in one check" -- why do you say this? See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

"you have to do it in one check"

I was intrigued by this assertion (no pun intended).

It seems to me that *four* constraints are not only possible but desirable (to provide increased granularity of failure messages) e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT Gender_legal_values 
    CHECK ( DEP_GENDER IN ( 'M', 'F' ) );

ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT Related_legal_values 
    CHECK ( RELATED_HOW IN ( 'Son', 'Daughter', 'Spouse' ) );

ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT Female_legal_values
    CHECK ( DEP_GENDER = 'M' OR RELATED_HOW IN ( 'Daughter', 'Spouse' ) );

ALTER TABLE DEPENDANT ADD CONSTRAINT Male_legal_values
    CHECK ( DEP_GENDER = 'F' OR RELATED_HOW IN ( 'Son', 'Spouse' ) );
```

Comment: Read the author's comment - he asked if he is supposed to add additional trigger for `dep_gender = 'M'`. If he did that, he would end up with two checks that would not allow any record to be inserted into the table. That's why I said that he has to do it in one check, not two how he was going to. +1 for those checks.